# I have two browsers open side by side of the same domain. I would like to drag selected rows of one grid to another browser. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two browsers open in dual monitor setup. I have certain html5 rows (grid) open in one browser. I would like to be able to drag those selected rows and drop in another browser. Now I can drag files in desktop or any image icons out of web browser and drop it wherever I want. However, I was wondering if same can be done with grid (or html5 tr elements).

Thank you for any help the community can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possble. This website is doing it: http://decafbad.com/2009/07/drag-and-drop/api-demos.html#delegated

Comment: Wow! Nice one, I've checked it between `Chrome` and `IE10`, it worked +1 :-)

Comment: Thank you Borre. 2 questions asked and both got answered by you in record time. You rock!!!